# How to get error results from a promise then at the same time

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

At the end of a promise, I want to call a callback that expects `err` and `results` parameters. like so:

```
function callback(err, results) {
  console.log("error", err);
  console.log("result", results);
}

function async() {
  return Promise.reject({"undefined": true});
}

// what i want
// async().then((err, results) => callback(err, results));
// what works
async().then(results => (), err => ());
```

But promise doesn't work like that.

Comment: What it's `results` supposed to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A word of caution (as learned from experience): Be careful when mixing promises and callbacks. It can make things tricky later on.

However, to get *exactly* what you're asking for you can resolve your async function with an array, and then use array destructuring to pass (sometimes called "spreading") the arguments to your callback: (object destructuring as shown in the other answer is also a reasonable option)

```js
function callback(err, results) {
  console.log("error: ", err);
  console.log("result: ", results);
}

function async() {
  return Promise.resolve(["your errors", "your results" ]);
}

async().then(([error, results]) => callback(error, results));
```

This does what you want, but it's important to note what kinds of issues can come with this code. The `async()` function will need to "break the rules" with promise chaining, by resolving the promise with an error. (Either "resolve the error" and/or "reject the good results"). Plus, the order of that array matters. Even if it's an object, simple things like proper spelling of object properties (i.e., "err" prop vs. "error") can cause issues.

Also, in the callback function, it will likely be necessary to have some conditional that checks the error first and handles it before doing anything with the results.

If, however, *only* promises are used, then the code can be cleaned up a bit like this:

```js
function async(){
  var err = 'sad face'; // Play with these vars to see what happens
  var results = 123;
  if( err ){
    return Promise.reject(err);
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(results);
  }
}

async()
.then((resp) => { console.log(resp) /* Work with resp, no conditionals needed :) Merrily proceed with your remaining code */  })
.catch((err) => { console.error(err)/* Err occurred, handle it here */ })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try rejecting with an object with two properties `error` and `results`. Then use destructuring and call your `callback`, like so:

```js
function callback(err, results) {
  console.log("error: ", err);
  console.log("result: ", results);
}

function async() {
  return Promise.reject({error: "your errors", results: "your results" });
}

async().catch(({error, results}) => callback(error, results));
```

But remember that `resolve` is for your success results and `reject` for your errors.